# Razor + Javascript weird error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I saw a very very weird error at my razor codes see the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@if (Model.SomeVerification)
{
   <text>
   if (startHour.getTime() >= maxStartHour.getTime() || startHour.getTime() < maxStartHour.getTime()) {
      if (!(checkIN.valueOf() <= currentNow.setDate(now.getDate() + 1).valueOf())) {
      //The code goes on...
      }
   }
  </text>
}
</script>
```

The  code syntax is just perfect but when I try to run it, I have the following error:

> Message Parser Error: End of file reached or unexpected character
>   before the "" mark could be analyzed. Elements within blocks of markup
>   should be complete. They must be self-closing ("
> ") or have
>   corresponding end tags ("
>
> Hello "). If you wanted to display a
>   "<" character, use the "<" HTML entity.

The trouble was the "<" at "<=", but I didn't understand why since I have other blocks with "<" alone, without the "=". Does anyone have seen that before and solved it with a better solution than  mine? I've solved just changing the if position:

```
if (!(currentNow.setDate(now.getDate() + 1).valueOf() >= checkIN.valueOf() ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you try placing the script tags inside your razor if block instead of using the text tag?

Example:

```
@if (Model.SomeVerification)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
       if (startHour.getTime() >= maxStartHour.getTime() || startHour.getTime() < maxStartHour.getTime()) {
          if (!(checkIN.valueOf() <= currentNow.setDate(now.getDate() + 1).valueOf())) {
          //The code goes on...
          }
       }
    </script>
}
```

Comment: @LaszloPapp It was before he added the example above. I need to remove my comment.

Comment: @LaszloPapp My bad then.

Comment: Very good it's definitely a better solution than mine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need yo use the **@:** Syntax to tell Razor to parse each if statement as text.
If you had only one if statement the text tag would work but since you have two if statements nested it's better to use @: syntax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@if (Model.SomeVerification)
{

   @:if (startHour.getTime() >= maxStartHour.getTime() || startHour.getTime() < maxStartHour.getTime()) {
      @:if (!(checkIN.valueOf() <= currentNow.setDate(now.getDate() + 1).valueOf())) {
      //The code goes on...
      }
   }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Yep, I could use it, but I don't have only 2 lines of javascript code it's almost 50. So, I prefer avoiding this option.

Answer (score 0):

To "cheat" Razor just add a comment at the end of the line with the opposite parenthesis:

```
if (!(checkIN.valueOf() <= currentNow.setDate(now.getDate() + 1).valueOf())) { //>
```